# Best way to read data and store from file?

Tags: c#, filereader, streamreader

I have a text file which stores data in this manner:

```
Player name: NAME HERE
Speed: 7
Strength: 9
Stamina: 4
Player name: ANOTHER NAME HERE
Speed: 5
Strength: 8
Stamina: 3
```

The same file contains about fifteen different players, and I want to gather values from each of them, store in a temporary race variable, then calculate the mean value of the speed strength and stamina and present a winner. My first idea was to use regular expression but I am currently investigating if there are another, more sustainable way to do this.

This is for a side project of mine and any help is welcome. Thanks

Comment: It is not clear if your file contains all possible attributes for each player or not. For example the above abstract is missing `Player name` for the second record

Comment: Someone edited my thread, there was two player names. I will fix this

Comment: If you control the file layout I would suggest XML. C# has really convenient and powerful XML processing tools. If not, let us know if all items are always present for all players and are they always in the same order?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with XML at all, maybe I should do some research. To answer your question: Yes, they are always present and in the same order/formula.

Comment: A "modern" way of doing this might be to serialize to/from JSON. No direct parsing needed if you use a JSON library.

Comment: As a quick and ugly solution you can parse for known lengths. Essentially instead of using regular expressions read the file line by line and you know when your data starts at which line. E.g. Player name starts  at position 14 ( = index 13) and so on. I won't post that as an answer because that is dirty and difficult to maintain because each simple change in the file requires rewriting your application and counting characters again. Again XML or maybe JSON as @crashmstr suggested are the way to go if you write the files initially.

Comment: @FrankJ that is not a bad suggestion, although very tedious indeed. Thank you for your contribution, let me know if you have anything else in mind!

Comment: I echo Frank's suggestion to use XML - this is exactly the sort of problem it was designed to solve. I think you'll find that parsing this data using XML is far less tedious than some of the other methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your Race Class Structure:

```
public class Race
{
    public string Name;
    public int Speed;
    public int Strength;
    public int Stamina;
}
```

Read your data in from your text file, and instantiate your `Race` objects and collect them into a `List<Race>`.  Once collected you can call `Average()` from your `List` to get your results.

```
string[] myTextFileLines = File.ReadAllLines(myTextFile);

List<Race> myRaces = new List<Race>();
for (int i = 0; i < myTextFileLines.Length; i += 4)
{
    myRaces.Add(new Race()
                    {
                        Name = myTextFileLines[i].Substring(myTextFileLines[i].IndexOf(":") + 2),
                        Speed = Convert.ToInt32(myTextFileLines[i + 1].Substring(myTextFileLines[i + 1].IndexOf(":") + 2)),
                        Strength = Convert.ToInt32(myTextFileLines[i + 2].Substring(myTextFileLines[i + 2].IndexOf(":") + 2)),
                        Stamina = Convert.ToInt32(myTextFileLines[i + 3].Substring(myTextFileLines[i + 3].IndexOf(":") + 2)),
                    });
}

Console.WriteLine("Avg Speed: {0}", myRaces.Average(r => Convert.ToDouble(r.Speed)));
Console.WriteLine("Avg Strength: {0}", myRaces.Average(r => Convert.ToDouble(r.Strength)));
Console.WriteLine("Avg Stamina: {0}", myRaces.Average(r => Convert.ToDouble(r.Strength)));
Console.ReadLine();
```

Results (using the exact data you provided in your question):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An example of the XML solution:

Players.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<players>
  <player name="Alice">
    <speed>7</speed>
    <strength>9</strength>
    <stamina>4</stamina>
  </player>
  <player name="Bob">
    <speed>5</speed>
    <strength>8</strength>
    <stamina>3</stamina>
  </player>
</players>
```

C# Code

```
    private class Player
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Speed { get; set; }
        public int Strength { get; set; }
        public int Stamina { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Name: " + Name + Environment.NewLine +
                   "Speed: " + Speed + Environment.NewLine +
                   "Strength: " + Strength + Environment.NewLine +
                   "Stamina: " + Stamina + Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }

    private static void PrintXmlPlayers(XmlNode players)
    {
        foreach (XmlNode player in players.SelectNodes("player"))
        {
            string playerName = player.Attributes["name"].InnerText;
            int playerSpeed = XmlConvert.ToInt32(player["speed"].InnerText);
            int playerStrength = XmlConvert.ToInt32(player["strength"].InnerText);
            int playerStamina = XmlConvert.ToInt32(player["stamina"].InnerText);

            Player aPlayer = new Player
            {
                Name = playerName,
                Speed = playerSpeed,
                Strength = playerStrength,
                Stamina = playerStamina
            };

            Console.WriteLine(aPlayer);
        }
    }

    private static void TestXml()
    {
        // path of document is relative to executable
        const string xmlPath = "../../Players.xml";

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(xmlPath);

        XmlNode players = doc["players"];
        PrintXmlPlayers(players);

        XmlNode alice = players.SelectSingleNode("player[@name='Alice']");
        string aliceOldString = alice["strength"].InnerText;
        alice["strength"].InnerText = "10";
        doc.Save(xmlPath);

        PrintXmlPlayers(players);

        alice["strength"].InnerText = aliceOldString;
        doc.Save(xmlPath);
    }
```

Output

```
Name: Alice
Speed: 7
Strength: 9
Stamina: 4

Name: Bob
Speed: 5
Strength: 8
Stamina: 3

Name: Alice
Speed: 7
Strength: 10
Stamina: 4

Name: Bob
Speed: 5
Strength: 8
Stamina: 3
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. How would a write to the XML file look like? Maybe Alice becomes stronger (lets say 10)

Answer (score 0):

If the file format is fixed, one way to go about this is to use `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines` to get every line in the file, and then loop over lines, splitting the key (left of the `:`) and the value (right of the `:`). Populate some sort of data object (`PlayerObject` in below example) with the values that you read from the file as you process each line.

```
PlayerObject player = new PlayerObject();
string[] allLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(FILE_PATH_HERE);
foreach(string dataPair in allLines)
{
    string[] pair = dataPair.Split(new[] { ':' });
    if(pair.Length == 2)
    {
        switch(pair[0])
        {
            case "Player name": /*process pair[1]*/ break;
            case "Speed": /*process pair[1]*/ break;
            //other possible key strings here
            //recommend defining these as constants
        }
    }
}
```

This would allow you to re-order the parameters in the file (or support different orderings at least), and if any parameters are missing, they can be pre-set to some default value in the data object.

The only thing missing from your format would be some kind of sentinel value between records. Right now you could assume that each player is delineated by a new "Player name" entry, and start populating the next `PlayerObject` once you read in the next "Player name".